# Dynamically pass a Product ID as the main Product Field on a Gravity Form (Product Add On)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I've got a great form set up to allow the building of a complex product and then add it to the cart (using the GForms Product Add on).  All lif this is perfect on the actual Woocommerce product page.

**What I'd love to do is have this form embedded on a page and populate the Product ID dynamically,** so that the form still picks up the product details and will add the new Item to the cart just as it does on a shop page. Having it on its own page (or on any page of the site) will allow us to offer a larger, focused experience to select all the options.

I've been looking into the code and the docs but I can't seem to make it work.  The code references product_id everywhere, but the dynamic field option is name.  So is this possible?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If the data you are attempting to map is simple then the following snippet plus Gravity Forms default `{embed_post`} and `{custom_field}` merge tags can get you there:

https://gravitywiz.com/dynamic-products-via-post-meta/

If your data is more advanced (like mapping product attributes), check out Gravity Form Populate Anything:

https://gravitywiz.com/documentation/gravity-forms-populate-anything/

Comment: Thanks for the tip Dave! The only data I really need is the (I think) is the $product variable. And I need a standard Add to Cart button.  If I’m looking at the source right, that powers everything else happening in the form and on the page. So at the end, the user can tap add to cart and everything will work. My initial thought is to set up a new custom template, then store a $product var in the template which gravity forms product add on form would access.  “Should” be like on the standard shop pages.  I’ll see if I can get this to work based on your comment. Thanks!!